# cmake: package config for installing arbitrary file dependencies for a target

Tags: cmake

I am creating a cmake package config file (a Foo-config.cmake) for a pre-existing .dll not created by cmake.

The annoying thing is that the .dll depends on some data files.

When a user consumes my package in his own cmake project, I want the `INSTALL` target to install both the .dll *and* data files to his specified install location.  I don't want him to have to write extra `install()` rules to do that.

1. Is it good practice to write the `install()` rules directly in my Foo-config.cmake?  Or is there a better way to do this, maybe with `set_target_properties()`?  I just couldn't find the appropriate property for associating arbitrary file dependencies to a target.
2. In an alternate universe where this .dll didn't already exist and I had to create it myself using cmake, would I need to create a custom Foo-config.cmake, or is there something in cmake that can automatically generate it for me to achieve the same thing?

FWIW the .dll is an internal legacy library and is normally built by Visual Studio and uploaded in a .zip file to our internal artifactory.  I want us to migrate away from manually pulling down .zip files from artifactory and manually integrating the files into Visual Studio projects.

Comment: Why would a user of your package want to install your package? The user wants to use your package, and install his program. If the user would want to install Foo, he would compile and install Foo. If the user wants to use Foo, he will want to use Foo, not install it.

Comment: The user wants to install the .dll because their program depends on it to run.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added some additional context.  This is for legacy internal libraries, with the larger goal of migrating away from manually futzing with msbuild projects.

Comment: This is still confusing why would you want to install it as part of your application. In windos, you first install VC++ redistributable, which is a collection of .dll, then you insatll a program that uses VC++. Separately. If user would have two programs with same set of .dll installed to same location, they would overwrite each other, leaving system in inconsistent state.

Comment: Is it that confusing?  Let's say I want to create a docker container with all the dependencies needed for an application.  Certain dependencies are dlls created by projects that know nothing about cmake or have no installer or aren't available on any package manager.  I want to collect all dependencies for the application at once.  Is that so strange?  What about cmake's $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:tgt>?  Maybe that can be leveraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found that there are a couple different ways to do this:

- In the config file, simply create one or more variables for the files/dirs you want to install.  Then install those using `install(FILES)` and/or `install(DIRECTORY)`.  More info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361538/189341
- Use `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)`.  More info:

  - https://discourse.cmake.org/t/installing-a-pre-built-module-and-its-various-dependencies/5227
  - [How to use cmake file( GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES in an install statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884439/how-to-use-cmake-file-get-runtime-dependencies-in-an-install-statement)

Answer (score -1):

> Is it good practice to write the install() rules directly in my Foo-config.cmake?

No.

From 480 *-config.cmake and *Config.cmake files on my system none calls `install()`.

> Or is there a better way to do this, maybe with set_target_properties()?

No.

> In an alternate universe where this .dll didn't already exist and I had to create it myself using cmake, would I need to create a custom Foo-config.cmake

No. This is unrelated to if you create a .dll or not. If .dll exists, there is no need to create Foo-config.cmake anyway. It is your choice that you want to (or make users to) use `find_package`.

> is there something in cmake that can automatically generate it for me

No.

---

If you don't intent to support `find_package` features - `VERSION`  `OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS` `PATHS` `HINTS` `CONFIGS` etc. - then just go with `include()`. `find_package` is just `include()` with some extra options.

If you want to have `install()` in your `find_package`, then just protect it with a variable, like `if (FOO_DO_INSTALL) install(....) endif()`.